# How can I use Binary search to print all the duplicates strings in a sorted array?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, search, binary-search

Just Using the Binary Search, how to get requested element with the duplicates, as the duplicates will be one after the other,what should be the conditions in the search?

Lets say this is the given array,entered by the user, and we have to search if "efg" exists, we don't know the indexes, neither how many times it'ss repeating,but  if it exists, print the number of times its repeating times.

```
array[][10]={"abc","efg","efg","jkl","jkl","jhk"}
```

Comment: If you have the position from a binary search, look at the index before and after it, see if they're also equal.

Comment: If the duplicates are next to each other, you can just iterate over the array and print them.

Comment: @ChrisMM yea, but like we need to search for the element itself, but we don't know how many times its repeating too.

Comment: Look before it ... is that equal? No - move on. Yes - look before that one. Repeat.

Comment: @akz0 _"but we don't know how many times its repeating too"_ and why should it matter for the search itself?. Just search for the element and as soon you find it look left and right to count how many times it is contained in the array

Comment: @ChrisMM we can not just look in one direction. The search could land us in the middel of the repeating elements. So we need to look in both directions.

Comment: @Ackdari so you are saying like implement binary search for both halves, left and right   again to find the same element? like in recursion?

Comment: @Ackdari, I'm aware. My original comment said both directions. Second comment was example for left only, but should be for right side as well.

Comment: There is a standard algorithm for this: `std::equal_range`

Comment: We will have to implement binary search here 2 times. In first implementation we will find the starting index of range of the given string and in 2nd implementation we will find the end index of range of given string.

Comment: Research `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `upper_bound` to find the first element after `"efg"` greater than it and `lower_bound` to find the first instance of `"efg"`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> V{ "abc", "efg", "efg", "jkl", "jkl", "jhk" };
    cout << upper_bound(V.cbegin(), V.cend(), "efg") - lower_bound(V.cbegin(), V.cend(), "efg") << endl;
}
```

Edit: To improve on it, you can first use `lower_bound` to check if the string exists in the array. If it does then use `upper_bound` to calculate the no. of instances.

Comment: This assumes the elements are sorted. Where is this stated?

Comment: In the heading.

Comment: As user `eerorika` pointed out, there is a better function that does exactly what is asked for, `std::equal_range`. It should be faster than calling these two functions.

Comment: `auto p = std::equal_range(V.cbegin(), V.cend(), "efg"); std::cout << std::distance(p.first, p.second);`

Comment: @ChrisMM if the string doesn't exist in the array then that would do double the work.

Comment: @lucieon, not if `equal_range` is properly implemented. MSVC's `equal_range` is actually much more efficient, since it finds the one entry first (if none exists, it stops), then uses `lower_bound` to find the first entry before the item it found, and `upper_bound` to find the last item after the one which was found. Your implementation would require re-searching both...effectively finding the first entry twice. Also, your code implementation is still double the work (although I see you made an edit to add that as a comment)

Comment: @ChrisMM does it say like that in C++ standard? If so kindly tell me where can I check it out. I looked around a bit online and it says it returns `make_pair(lower_bound(first, last, value), upper_bound(first, last, value))`. Also when "if" comes in the statement, we should stop making assumptions then and there.

Comment: @lucieon, it's an implementation detail. The standard doesn't specify how the function gets implemented, only what it does. I assume you are referring to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range)'s possible implementation. That's only a possibility, and I think they keep those fairly simple to give an idea. I'm not sure how gcc or clang implement `equal_range`, but I'd be surprised if they didn't do the same/similar to MSVC.

Comment: @ChrisMM exactly my point. Standard doesn't tell how to implement it but gives an upper bound on the complexity the implementation should have (from where I read) which is : At most 2 ∗ log2 (last - first) + O(1) comparisons. So it can just return the `make_pair` way.

Comment: @lucieon, by that argument, the `upper_bound` can be implemented to loop for 6 hours doing nothing but wasting CPU cycles. It would still be O(log n). All I was doing was giving an alternative example, using `equal_range`, which Dialecticus pointed out as a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I use Binary search to print all the duplicates strings in a sorted array?

A simple, probably non-optimal algorithm to find the range:

First use binary search to find the first occurrence. This variant of binary search is called "lower bound".

Then, use binary search to find the last occurrence. This variant of binary search is called "upper bound". Here, we can optimise a bit by limiting the search to start from the found lower bound rather than beginning of the original  linerly untilrange.

---

However, there is no need to implement it yourself since the standard library has you covered: `std::equal_range`.

---

That said, if your intention is to iterate the elements afterwards, then there is no need to search for the end because you'll encounter it while iterating. In such case, simply find the beginning with lower_bound, then iterate the elements linearly while performing the desired operation ("print" in your example) until non-equal element is found.

Comment: `upper_bound` returns the first element occurring after the element you're looking for to keep up with the C++ notion of `[first, last)`.

Comment: @lucieon Which is exactly what one would want to find when searching for the end of the range.

Comment: My comment was in response to your comment "Then, use binary search to find the last occurrence. This variant of binary search is called "upper bound"." It doesn't find the last occurrence but the first occurrence of the element greater than the one you're finding.